# Adding same density plots across all facets

Tags: r

I have an example code below. I have built a figure with ggplot and it is almost there, but I would like to add an additional curve across all facets from y. The final output should look like the image attached. I'm not sure how I would do this.

```
x <- iris[-1:-3]
bw <- 1
nbin <- 100
y <- head(iris, 50)[2]

ggplot(x, aes(x = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = bw *..count.., fill = Species), size = 1, alpha = 0.4) + 
  facet_wrap(~Species)+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::math_format(10^.x), limits = c(0, 5), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, NA)) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "b", short=unit(-1,"mm"), mid=unit(-2,"mm"), long=unit(-3,"mm")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip='off') + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
                                      panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA))
```

[image]

Comment: Your sample code generates a plot that has many missing elements compared to your desired output, so it is not at all clear to me (1) what you are asking for, (2) where the data for your "additional curve" comes from or (3) where is your fluorecence data? (4)  I don't see a curve that is common to all three facets in your desired output.

Comment: The image is just a sample figure. I basically want to add the density curve from "y" onto each facet that is written into my ggplot code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you are looking to achieve?

I'm sure there are better ways; basically I've generated three versions of the `y` data and shuffled the grouping variables to allow ggplot's `facet_wrap` and `fill` to manage the appearance.

It would be great if there is way to make one set of data appear in all facets without this repetition.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x1 <- 
  x %>% 
  mutate(var = "Petal width") %>% 
  rename(val = Petal.Width) 

    

df <- 
  y %>% 
  mutate(var = "Sepal width",
         spp1 = "setosa",
         spp2 = "versicolor",
         spp3 = "virginica") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("spp"), names_to = "temp", values_to = "Species") %>% 
  select(-temp) %>% 
  rename(val = Sepal.Width )%>% 
  bind_rows(x1) %>% 
  mutate(g1 = case_when(var == "Sepal width" ~ "all species: sepal width",
                        TRUE ~ paste0(Species, ": petal width")))

ggplot(df, aes(x = val)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = bw *..count.., fill = g1), size = 1, alpha = 0.4) + 
  facet_wrap(~Species)+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::math_format(10^.x), limits = c(0, 5), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, NA)) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "b", short=unit(-1,"mm"), mid=unit(-2,"mm"), long=unit(-3,"mm")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip='off') + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
                                      panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: What version of R are you using? I get an error from running x1 and df

Comment: R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24) -- "Arbor Day", RStudio Version 1.3.959. Have you installed `dplyr` and `tidyr`?